# On Joule's free expansion experiment

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

While reading through an introductory textbook in Thermodynamics, I've come across a series of arguments that seem somewhat arbitrary/vague, on which I'd like some clarification.

To begin with, the idea defining the internal energy of a system as 
$$ \Delta U = Q - W \,\,\, (1) $$
seems fine, and the differential formulation of (1) as the sum of two "improper" differentials
$$ dU = d'Q - d'W \,\,\, $$
is also understandable. If a system undergoes an reversible adiabatic transformation, then it is also acceptable to me that
$$ dU = - dW \,\,\, (2) $$
which turns the infinitesimal work into a proper differential since the very definition of internal energy as a function of state would not make sense otherwise.

However, when it comes to Joule's free expansion experiment, a few things don't quite seem to add up. Supposing we had a system consisting of two diathermic recipients A and B of equal volume and connected by a valve which keeps an amount of gas trapped inside one of them, say, recipient A. This system is initially in thermal equilibrium with a small water calorimeter whose temperature we have measured beforehand, and which is small so that it is sensible to small temperature variations in the gas. We then quickly open the valve, allowing the gas to freely flow from A to B. At the end of the process, then, when the system once again reaches equilibrium, we should have measured that the calorimeter's temperature has not changed.

It is then said that since the system consisting of *both* the A and B recipients does not change its volume, no work is exerted by the gas and thus (2) gives out 
$$ dU = 0 \,\,\, (3) $$
This sounds debatable, since by definition this process is *not* quasi-static/reversible. Why should (2) be still valid? However, let's for the moment assume this as true, and proceed by stating that by looking at the internal energy as a function of temperature and volume, we should have that
$$ dU = \bigg ( \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V} \bigg )_T dV + \bigg ( \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial T} \bigg )_V dT $$
And from (3) and from the experimental the fact that the temperature does not vary,
$$ \bigg ( \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V} \bigg )_T dV = 0 $$
The next argument is that in this free expansion dV is "clearly" not equal to 0, thus arriving at
$$  \bigg ( \dfrac{\partial U}{\partial V} \bigg )_T = 0 $$
hence proving that the internal energy is a function of temperature only. However, in order to arrive at (3), wasn't *precisely the contrary* assumed? That is, that the volume in the system remains unchanged?

Is this confusion some sort of grave misunderstanding on my part? Also, this whole idea of "energy" and "work" in Thermodynamics seems a bit too vague to me. Is there any way of defining them more precisely, as it is done in Mechanics, or is this imprecision proposital, so as to make them applicable to a wider range of situations?

Comment: The internal energy is not "defined" in terms of work and heat.  The internal energy is a physical property of the material, representing the sum of the kinetic energy of the molecules, and the potential energy of the mutual interactions.

Comment: @ChesterMiller, while internal energy was in later developments of physics theory partitioned into various contributions due to kinetic energy and potential energy, originally in thermodynamics, the existence of internal energy and its definition is based on the first law of thermodynamics, valid for any cyclic process: $\oint dQ+dW = 0 \implies U(\mathbf X) = U(\mathbf X_0) + \int_{\mathbf X_0}^{\mathbf X} dQ+dW$.

Answer (score -1):

In the experiment you described, the gas is in a rigid container, and you are considering the contents of the container as your system.  The gas is incapable of doing any work on the rigid container that encloses it since the displacement of the container walls is zero.  Therefore, $\Delta U=0$.

In addition to this, in the Joule experiment, the temperature change is exactly zero only for an ideal gas.  For a real gas, there is a small, but finite, temperature change.  Therefore, the Joule experiment is not an indication that the $(\partial U/\partial V)_T=0$ for all gases.  In your further studies, once you learn about entropy S and the equation dU=TdS-PdV, you will learn how to analytically prove that $(\partial U/\partial V)_T=0$ for a gas that satisfies PV=nRT.

Comment: But then how are we allowed to argument that $ dV $ is non-zero later on, in order to prove the internal energy temperature-only dependence? What volume V is being analyzed, after all?

Comment: See my further discussion.  In proving this, we are considering the general behavior of a gas, not specifically in this one particular experiment.

Comment: Yes .  Thanks .  I’ve gone back and added the zero.